# sporadic homepage timeouts Apache2

Tags: lamp

Running apache2/php/mysql on an Ubuntu instance on slicehost. Monitoring homepage accessibility using offsite monitoring tools which test a TCP connection to port 80. A few times a day the homepage times out (not responsive) or long load time (> 40 seconds.)

I'm monitoring CPU, load average, TCP active opens, network traffic, and memory usage. Not seeing anything that points to a problem. The load average is consistently high on this machine (between 6 and 12) but the timeouts do not occur regularly.

Apache config looks normal with MaxClients 150, StartServers 5, MaxRequestsPerChild 0.

Anyone have any thoughts as to where I should look to fix this and/or what parameters I should be monitoring?